# Qt: How to adjust the size of a QTextEdit object automatically

Tags: c++, qt

How can I automatically adjust the size of a QTextEdit object to automatically resize itself when the text string is larger than the given geometry?

In my example below, I define the geometry of the QTextEdit box to be 100x100.  However, the text string that I would like to display could be much larger than that.

```
void MainWindow::display_text()
{
    QTextEdit *text = new QTextEdit(this);
    text->setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::NoWrap);
    text->setFontPointSize(24);

    /* Set the text box to be 100x100 */
    text->setGeometry(1, 1, 100, 100);

    /* The destination field may be too large to fit in the text box */
    QString arg = QString("Destination: %1").arg(destination);
    text->append(arg);

    text->show();
}
```

I would like the text string to be visible (ie no scrolling) and word-wrapping is turned off.

Comment: Is it gonna be a single line or multiline text? Also, do you want it to expand while typing or when you insert text programatically?

Comment: Each append should be a single line, stretching out to the full width of the window if necessary.  There will also be multiple appends, each one line.  But I know how many total lines I will have, so calculating the y-axis geometry is not strictly necessary.  Also, the text is populated programmatically.  I do not require any user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QFontMetrics` to calculate that.

```
QFontMetrics fm(text->font());
QString myText = text->toPlainText();
int calcWidth = fm.width(myText);
int calcHeight = fm.height(myText);
```

From that point you can use those values to set the geometry to whatever dimension you like.

```
text->setGeometry(1, 1, calcWidth, calcHeight);//Or whatever calculations you want
```

To change the size as you go, use signals and slots and just call that code again. `QTextEdit` has a nice `textChanged` signal you can use.

Comment: This solution works for finding the width, however it will not compile for the height(?!).  I get 'error: no matching function for call to 'QFontMetrics::height(QString&)'.

Comment: Also, fm does not seem to take into account setFontPointSize(24).  The pixel size returned is significantly less than what it should be.  But if I multiply the pixels by the font size divided by 10, it comes out pretty close.  So it would be calcWidth*(24/10).